# How do I echo one HTML line in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to echo this line in PHP simply by using "echo", but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

```
echo '<p><input type="button" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="window.location ='viewusers.php'" /></p>'
```

Comment: Why do you need to use PHP to echo that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `"` inside what you want to echo. All you need is escape quotes.

This should do it:

```
echo '<p><input type="button" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="window.location =\'viewusers.php\'" /></p>';
```

Another option is to do it in blocks. This would be better if your doing a lot of echos like that. Such as:

```
<?php
if($output == "hello"): 
?>

<p><input type="button" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="window.location ='viewusers.php'" /></p>

<php 
else:
?>
<p>Doesn't equal hello</p>

<?php
endif;
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the quotes, or better, change to single quotes like this: (still needs escaping at the end there)

```
echo '<p><input type="button" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="window.location =\'viewusers.php\'" /></p>';
```

It's better to do single quotes because then php doesn't parse it like it does with double quotes. A better explanation is in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Another option is to close the php block, like this: (then you don't have to worry about escaping quotes)

```
<?php
  [your php code]
?>
[your html line or block]
<?php
  [more php]
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo '<p><input type="button" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="window.location =\'viewusers.php\'" /></p>'
```

Notice the simple quote

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your double quotes like this (because you use them to delimit your string):

```
echo "<p><input type=\"button\" name=\"Back\" value=\"Back\" onclick=\"window.location ='viewusers.php'\" /></p>";
```

OR (As per your edit with single quotes)

```
echo '<p><input type="button" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="window.location =\'viewusers.php\'" /></p>';
```

Comment: Or simply escaping the two (2) single-quotes would suffice. See answer by yvoyer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326430/how-to-echo-one-html-line-in-php/4326453#4326453).

Comment: @manxing changed their question after I posted this. Thanks for the heads up though, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to escape the `"` which are found in a string enclosed in `"`.

Alternatively to avoid escaping you can use here docs as:

```
echo <<<FOO
<p><input type="button" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="window.location ='viewusers.php'" /></p>
FOO;
```

Comment: You should remove the first and last double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone has said, you need to escape the quotes within the string you're echoing. 
    echo "

";

Or, better yet, since this line itself isn't actually dynamic, end the php block and just leave it as HTML:

```
?>
<p><input type="button" name="Back" value="Back" onclick="window.location ='viewusers.php'" /></p>
```